# Playing apple music from AVFoundation for visualization

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, apple-musickit

I am working on a music app where I can do some sound analysis, my end goal is to integrate Apple Music API in my app where users can search songs. When the song is played I want to show a type of soundwave/spectrogram. For sound visualization, I have AVFoundation which help me analyze song but the songs need to be downloaded. As the Music API returns only song IDs that could be played using the Apple MediaPlayer framework only. Is there any API provided by Apple for doing sound analysis or some workaround to play Apple Music songs using AVFoundation?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: What happens in the background when we play a song using MediaPlayer.play. Does it download the entire song at once?

Comment: I imagine the song is streamed, so it would download just enough to reliably sustain playback. Music streaming services don't want untrusted code to touch their samples because of copyright, contracts etc. Spotify used to have sample level access for VIP but they cut it off 2 years ago.